# Easy way to undraw Graphics

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm making a small UI where I need to hide the system cursor but still trace mouse movement around the screen. I am using `Graphics` as follows:

```
var interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow);
Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(interopHelper.Handle);

// Sometime later, OnMouseMovement
Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, cursorPos.X - 5, cursorPos.Y - 5, 10, 10);
```

I need to erase the drawing every so often. `Graphics.Clear(..)` forces a very slow redraw of the entire screen. I tried initializing the Graphics with my mainWindow's handle, but `mainWindow.InvalidateVisual()` does not clean up the drawn ellipses.

Is it possible to use `Graphics` in this way? Even better would be to have a single Ellipse object that I can move around the screen. How could I fix that?

Comment: Why are you trying to use GDI+ in WPF? That's also not the way to draw to a Device Context where GDI+ is actually used.

Comment: BTW, since the method you're using to produce the drawings generates an *unstable* *surface*, to clear it you just need to `Invalidate()` the Control and everything will vanish. Just add a public method that calls `this.Invalidate()`.

Comment: There does not appear to be anything at all in this question that makes it _about_ WPF, so that tag is inappropriate.

Comment: The root of your problem is here: `Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(interopHelper.Handle);` You should _never_ do that. The `Graphics` object for a window should be obtained _only_ from a `PaintEventArgs` object that is passed to a paint event handler. Persistent drawing should be done to an offscreen bitmap, which can be cleared efficiently if needed. It's not clear why you're using GDI+ here anyway; better would be to just use the WPF API.

Comment: @Jimi: that doesn't make this _about_ WPF. It just means that the GDI+ question came up as part of writing a WPF program.